# Want the message to appear after the typing effect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chatbot

I'm developing a chatbot using React.
I want to display a message after the typing effect for 1 second, as described in the source code.

Here is an example:

[image]

I don't have an image of the implementation, so I would like to ask for your help.

```
import React from "react";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import ListItemAvatar from "@material-ui/core/ListItemAvatar";
import Avatar from "@material-ui/core/Avatar";
import Ebisuke from "../assets/img/ebisuke.jpg";

import { TypingBalls } from "./index";

const Chat = (props) => {
  const isQuestion = props.type === "question";
  const classes = isQuestion ? "p-chat__row" : "p-chat__reverse";

  return (
    <>
      <ListItem className={classes}>
        {isQuestion && (
          <ListItemAvatar>
            <Avatar alt="icon" src={Ebisuke} />
          </ListItemAvatar>
        )}

        // display typing effect for 1 second
        <div className="p-chat__typing-balls-bubble">
          <TypingBalls />
        </div>

        // display message after typing effect
        <div
          className="p-chat__bubble"
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.text }}
        />

      </ListItem>
    </>
  );
};

export default Chat;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish this would be to add a `useEffect` for the `props.text` received in the component. Add a state to control the stage in which you are in - TYPING or DONE. Within the `useEffect`, set the stage to TYPING first. Add a `setTimeout` of one second, after which swtich the state to DONE.

Perhaps, this block of code would be helpful.

```
const [stage, setStage] = useState('TYPING');
const { text } = props;
useEffect(() => {
  setStage("TYPING");
  setTimeout(() => {
    setStage("DONE");
  }, 1000);
}, [text]);
```

Using the `stage` state, you can switch between the `TypingBalls` and `chat bubble`.

```
return (
    <>
      <ListItem className={classes}>
        {isQuestion && (
          <ListItemAvatar>
            <Avatar alt="icon" src={Ebisuke} />
          </ListItemAvatar>
        )}

        {stage === 'TYPING' ? (
          <div className="p-chat__typing-balls-bubble">
            <TypingBalls />
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div
            className="p-chat__bubble"
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.text }}
          />
        )}
      </ListItem>
    </>
  );
```

Check this CodeSandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-hertz-0r10n?file=/src/Child.js:94-280) for a simplified example.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.
You have helped me to solve the problem.
I learned a lot :)